# Qual a diferença entre roubo e assalto?

Tags: diferenças, vocabulário

Em Inglês, `assault`é um falso cognato de `assalto`, mas significa agressão, violência; não roubar. Já em Português, tanto `roubo` e `assalto` são empregados para designar subtração de bens. Há alguma diferença entre esses vocábulos?

Comment: Eu não sei a diferença entre esses dois, mas de repente já era uma boa colocar o "furto" junto, que tem muita gente que acha que significa o mesmo que "roubar".

Comment: Estava pensando exatamente nisso outro dia... intuitivamente uso um para quando a vitima não está presente e o outro quando sim.

Comment: Bem, furto e roubo possuem conceitos bem específicos no Código Penal. Apesar de popularmente roubo ser mais usado, inclusive quando se trata de furto. E assalto, por sua vez, já foi utilizado em algumas leis, mas nenhuma definiu o que é.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *roubo* tanto pode ser um furto como pode ser um assalto, no entanto no inglês a palavra *assault* realmente tem outro significado, que seria "ataque".

Conforme a fonte citada pelo [@BrunoLopes](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/575/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-roubo-e-assalto/#comment1372_576) no [michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=assalto), *assalto* é derivado da palavra assaltar:

> 1. Ação ou resultado de assaltar; assaltada, *ataque*, *investida*, surtida.
> 2. Arremetida súbita de fera, ladrão etc., por cilada ou traição.
> 3. Pedido insistente; importunação, instância.
> 4. Tentação: Os assaltos do demônio.
> 5. Acesso repentino de doença ou paixões.
> 6. Combate ou duelo simulado entre dois esgrimistas.
> 7. Esforços para conseguir alguma coisa difícil de obter.

Ou seja, é quando ocorre um ataque ou investida a uma pessoa ou local.

*Roubo* é a ação de *subtrair* para si ou para outrem (coisa alheia móvel), furtivamente ou com violência.

Então *roubo* é mais especifico para subtrair algo e pode ser um assalto ou não, *assalto* não é tão especifico, no entanto se caracteriza pelo *ataque*.

Por exemplo:

- Assalto a banco é um ataque, pois ocorre mais diretamente e ação é percebida pelas vitimas.
- Um roubo ou extravio de mercadoria de um mercado por um cliente não é considerado um ataque, mas sim um furto ou subtração.

Ou seja nem todo assalto será um roubo, mas todo assalto será um ataque.

**Fonte:**

- [Michaelis: roubo](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=roubo)
- [Michaelis: assalto](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=assalto)

Comment: Aconselho a não usar o dicionário informal como fonte, mesmo que esteja certo, porque esse site é igual o Wikipedia, qualquer um coloca o significado que achar que é. Um O Priberam ou o Michaelis, por exemplo.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Grato!

Comment: Corrigindo meu comentário: "Use* o Priberam ou o Michaelis ... "

Comment: Furto: quando não há uso de força, de arma, ou coação da vítima. Como em um ato furtivo, a vítima talvez nem perceba o furto até se dar conta que algo sumiu. Roubo: a vítima é intimidada, ameaçada geralmente com o uso de arma. Um supermercado pode ser vítima de furto se o ladrão pegou algo e escondeu na sua roupa, ou pegou e fugiu. Este supermercado teria sido roubado se o ladrão ameaçasse algum funcionário para conseguir o objeto do roubo ou dinheiro.

Comment: Um assalto geralmente remete a mais de um indivíduo assaltando o local com armas de fogo e fazendo as pessoas presentes de vítimas de suas ameaças ou do roubo. Mas pode pode ser um indivíduo roubando um caixa, e fugindo. Então, assalto é um roubo "mais dramático", ou seja, com ideia de ataque, e geralmente envolvendo dinheiro ou objetos de valor.